# Page resize for mobile

Tags: html, css, mobile

I have this div content, work well on pc screen and i want resize this div, automatically for mobile device. With a css or other. This div is include in a page that i don't have access, and i can use only inline css.

```
<div id="content" style=" margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;">
  <table style="margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;" class="table">
    <tr>
      <td>
        <div id="contentLiveEvent" style="display: block; margin-left: 1%; margin-right: 1%; margin-top: 1%; margin-bottom: 1%; align: center">
          <div id="player"></div>
          <script type="text/javascript">
            jwplayer("player").setup({
              "playlist": [{
                "sources": [{
                  "default": false,
                  "type": "hls",
                  "file": "https://stream/streamurl.m3u8",
                  "label": "0"
                }]
              }],
              "primary": "html5",
              "hlshtml": true,
              'bufferlength': '20',
              'width': '640px',
              'height': '480px',
              "autostart": true
            });
          </script>
        </div>
      </td>
      <td style="width: 100%">
        <div id="contentLiveChat">
          <iframe src="../mxChat/" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0" name="chat" width="343px" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" height="485px"></iframe>
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: You might want to have a look at flexbox, which is widely available in browsers for years: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Answer (score 0):

I used this code:

```
    function writeMeta() {
        //alert('ok');
        $("meta[name='viewport']").attr('content', 'width=device-width, initial-scale=0.4'); 
        //$("#page").html(''); 
    }
    window.onload = writeMeta;
```